# Change the order of factors

Tags: r

I would like a generic way to re order the factors which in my case are numbers of a vector without having to do it manually. For example:

`sizes <- factor(c(5,4,2,3,1))` should become `sizes <- factor(c(1,2,3,4,5))` I know that I can do it explicitly with just `sizes <- factor(c(1,2,3,4,5))` but I would like a more generic way that would put first the smaller value 1 and last the biggest value which may be any value.

Comment: `sort(sizes)` ?

Comment: the two are exactly the same, there is no ordering in factors unless you are dealing with ordinal data. In this case, 1,2,3,4,5 and 5,4,3,2,1 is exactly the same. Its like having Male and Female and another having Female and Male.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the tidyverse (forcats package), there is `fct_rev()`